# save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given djnago allauth resetpassword form

Tags: django, django-allauth

I need to add recaptcha field to allauth reset password form , i override the form according to [allauth documantion](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html)

this is resetpassword form in forms.py :

```
class MyCustomResetPasswordForm(ResetPasswordForm):
captcha = ReCaptchaField()

def save(self):

    # Ensure you call the parent class's save.
    # .save() returns a string containing the email address supplied
    email_address = super(MyCustomResetPasswordForm, self).save()

    # Add your own processing here.

    # Ensure you return the original result
    return email_address
```

and in settings.py :

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'reset_password':'user.forms.MyCustomResetPasswordForm'}
```

but i get this error :
TypeError at /accounts/password/reset/
save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py, line 70, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py, line 98, in dispatch
return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py, line 102, in post
response = self.form_valid(form) …
▶ Local vars
/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py, line 690, in form_valid
form.save(self.request) …

Comment: If you look closely at the documentation, you will see that when you call the parent class `save` method, you shouldn't include the `self` argument. You just need `email_address = super(MyCustomResetPasswordForm, self).save()`. Also, if you are using Python 3 you don't need the arguments for `super`. You just need `email_address = super().save()`.

Comment: well i removed self from save() and still the same error

Comment: Was the error for the same form, or a different form?

Comment: for the same form

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the entire traceback?

Comment: stackoverflow does not let me to post entire traceabck

Comment: You shouldn't be getting that same error unless the code is still calling save with a self parameter `save(self)`. Do you have similar code in other forms? They should all be `save()` except in the def lines,

Comment: I get this error at the url of reset password form not other forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the error is telling you is that your save() method has only one argument, but when it is being called it actually gets two, and that is because the save() method has an additional argument **commit**, as you can see on the [Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/models.py#L451).

You should also add it to your super().save() call.

You need to include it in your save() definition:

```
class MyCustomResetPasswordForm(ResetPasswordForm):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()
    def save(self, commit=True):
        # As evergreen pointed out, you don't need to pass any arguments to super() on Python 3.
        email_address = super().save(commit)
    
        # Add your own processing here.
    
        # Ensure you return the original result
        return email_address
```